Upper bound for norm of a matrix in system of equations
I have 2 systems of equations, all elements are between $[0,1]$,
\begin{align}
X = QZ \\
\tilde{X} = \tilde{Q} \tilde{Z},
\end{align}
where $Q$ and $\tilde{Q}$ are square matrices and $X, \tilde{X}, Z$ and $\tilde{Z}$ are vectors.
For a $p$-norm we have that,
\begin{align}
||X - \tilde{X}||_p \leq c_1 \\
||Z - \tilde{Z}||_p \leq c_2
\end{align}
Is it possible to find an upper bound for $|| Q - \tilde{Q}||_p$?
If somebody can steer me in a direction where I can find something related to this I would be grateful.

There is no such upper bound. The fact that two matrices when acting on close vectors produce close vectors as output don't imply that the matrices are close (means that the difference have small norm).
For example take $e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1, 0 \\
0, 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1, 100 \\ 
0, 100\end{pmatrix}$ then $Ae_1=Be_1=e_1$ But you can see that the matrices are not close to each other.
